# Why does Saxon Professional Edition uses finalize method in their factory implementations?

Tags: dom, saxon, xerces

Saxon Professional Edition uses finalize method in their factory implementations and it fills up the finalizer. Any idea on why the finalizer is used and not close() method on the interface level?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one place that Saxon includes a finalize() method, namely on the Configuration object, which is used in all editions. The Configuration underpins all the various APIs, for example there will be a Configuration within a TransformerFactory, an XPathFactory, a SchemaFactory, an XQJ DataSource, or a s9api Processor.

The action taken by the finalize method is to close the stream used for "standard error output", if this is not System.err. There are cases where it's impossible for the user to close this themselves, for example if they nominate a file to contain this data as a configuration property. The JAXP APIs don't provide any kind of close() method that we could use to trigger closing the stream, so the only way we can do it is on garbage collection. (We could provide a close() method on our implementation of the factory, but I don't think many users would notice its existence).

I would be grateful for more detail on the problems this causes. You talk of it "filling up the finalizer". This sounds to me as if you are creating and releasing a lot of Configuration objects. Perhaps you are creating lots of TransformerFactory objects? This would be very poor practice, because creating a TransformerFactory is expensive. Normally an application should create a single factory / Configuration and keep using it for ever; it's very rare that multiple Configurations are needed in a single application.

(By the way, you are asking a question here that really needs to be directed at the Saxon developers, not at the user community. So it would be much more appropriate to raise the question via the Saxonica support site at saxonica.plan.io. We try to keep an eye on questions raised here, but it's pure chance how long it takes us to notice them, and we don't give them the same priority as formal support requests.)